# How to set state based off DOM node info after initial render/re-renders? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, rerender

In my framework I need certain information about my React component's *state within the DOM* after initial renders and re-renders, which I then need to pass down to child components as *context*.

Specifically, I need to know if the rendered DOM node is the first/last child of its parent, and keep this information as state, so I'm doing something like:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.REF.current === this.REF.current.parentNode.firstChild) {
    this.setState({ isFirstChild: true });
  }
}
```

Calling *setState* here triggers a re-render, which is needed so the value can be passed to child components, which I'm doing through *context* - something like (stripped down):

```
render() {
  const contextValues = {
    ...this.context,
    ...this.state
  }

  return (
    <ContextProvider value={contextValues}>
      {this.props.children}
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

...now in my child components I can do `this.context.isFirstChild` to determine whether the parent is the first-child of its own parent.

***The issue...***

Setting state causes a re-render. Re-rendering causes a set-state. This sets React off into an infinite loop, yielding this error:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate`

It seems clear to my that *something* about my approach is wrong. I'm just not sure what. I considered that I should't be using `setState` here, but then I miss out on the crucial re-rendering which passes the parent state to children as context.

Comment: Is there no other way to figure out whether the given child is first? Is this about sorting a table using some 3rd party library or something like that? Anyway, the main issue is `Re-rendering causes a set-state.`. `render()` must not change state. Ever.

Comment: I'm unable to determine any other way - I thought there may have been a way without depending on the DOM but there doesn't seem to be. I'm building a css-in-js tool for React and trying to simulate the behaviour of certain pseudo selectors.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [mre] on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: @ChrisG there seems to be totally different errors on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-river-wglp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.REF.current === this.REF.current.parentNode.firstChild) {
    if (!this.state.isFirstChild) {
        this.setState({ isFirstChild: true });
    }        
  }
}
```

This way, you're not repeatedly calling setState with the same information that your state already has in it.

Comment: I thought to try something like this initially, makes sense in theory, let me give it a whirl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is every time you component updates, you are updating it again without any kind of break condition. This creates an infinite loop. You should check that `this.state.isFirstChild` is NOT **true** before updating it here.

Replace a small amount of code works for you.

```
      if (!this.state.isFirstChild) {
          this.setState({
              isFirstChild: true
          });
      }
```